# Can you "hijack" code suggestions for a certain class in InteliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, code-completion, annotation-processing

So I want is a plugin that changes what is suggested to the Developer for accordingly annotated classes.

The idea is to combine this with a code-generating annotation where I want the developers to have suggestions for the code (added methods) that will be generated. Obviously, though, the other classes should be unaffected by this.

Is there such a plugin?

Or if not, is there anything that would prevent me from writing one such plugin myself?

**UPDATE**

To make it clearer what I want to achieve:

```
@HasFoo //injects a `public Foo getFoo()` method (in addition to other code changes)
class MyTarget {}
```

so when you then use the `MyTarget` class

```
var target = new MyTarget();
Foo foo = target.getFoo(); //compiles
```

`getFoo()` should appear as a suggestion when typing `target.`

**UPDATE**

For example, `Foo` may be an interface and the code that implements it can be generated depending on the class and/or other annotations.

Or maybe it generates some static methods that provide some utility functions.

Etc.

I need IntelliJ to recognise that certain methods with a specific signature will be available after compilation, even though they aren't in the source code, by mapping the annotation to the public method signatures it generates.

Comment: Do you want to add your own quick fixes or intentions? Check this IntelliJ platform SDK documentation: https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support/quick_fix.html https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/custom_language_support/code_inspections_and_intentions.html

Comment: @Andrey If I'm reading this correctly, "intentions" require user-interaction (kind of like the "import XY" suggestion when you use a class that's not been imported yet, right? That's definitely not what I want. What I want is an annotation that will end up generating methods and I want the signatures of these method  to be available for code-completion when you're using the class. I'll add an example. :)

Comment: @Andrey please have a look at the update and see if that makes my intention clearer. :)

Comment: Still not exactly clear: do you want to Generate code from usage or Generate some code as a [generate](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generating-code.html#top) getter/setter/constructor functionality in IDE? Add an exact use case please.

Comment: @Andrey the code generation is absolutely IDE-independent, it happens automatically when you compile the code. method bodies, constructors, etc. get updated according to whatever the annotation is meant to specify. During that code generation, some public methods may be added to the annotated class. All I want the IDE to do is recognise that those methods will be generated at some point due to the annotation and offer type-inference and code completion for them. (`CTRL+Space`)

Comment: For this custom plugin would be required. See e.g. Lombok plugin - it provides similar functionality.